# How to append .md to any word before the delimiter ' "wikilink"'

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, tr

Thank you for taking the time to read this post.

As mentioned in the title, I'm trying to append .md to any word before the delimiter "wikilink". The issue is the word changes depending on the file and there are hundreds of files.

For example:

```
On the (example-info "wikilink") and the
(second-example "wikilink") platforms.
```

Should become:

```
On the (example-info.md "wikilink") and the
(second-example.md "wikilink") platforms.
```

Since the word changes depending on the file, I've attempted the following sed command. Unfortunately, this leaves a space between the word and .md

`gsed -r 's/(^.*)"wikilink"/\1.md "wikilink"/g' filename`

The result:

```
On the (example-info .md "wikilink") and the
(second-example .md "wikilink") platforms.
```

This doesn't have to be done with sed, it just seemed like the best tool to use.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sed 's/(\([^ ]*\) "wikilink")/(\1.md "wikilink")/g' file
On the (example-info.md "wikilink") and the
(second-example.md "wikilink") platforms.
```

This simply matches the word right after the opening parenthesis, up to the space after it, followed by the string `"wikilink")`.  The word is captured in in a capture group (`\(...\)`) and the replacement inserts `.md` after the word.